# Неправильно работает функция удаления последнего рядка в таблице

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Хочу удалить последний рядок в dataGridView1.Но всегда при первом удалении, удаляются два последних рядка, а не один, как должно, в чем проблема?

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MyCELL;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int AsciA = 65;
        //int currRow, currCol;
        int rowCount = 4;
        int colCount = 4;
        public static Dictionary<string,MyCell> dataSaver = new Dictionary<string,MyCell>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for(int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
                DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                column.CellTemplate = cell;
                int n = i + AsciA;
                string name = ((char)n).ToString();
                column.HeaderText = name;
                column.Name = name;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount-1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }
            SetRowNum(dataGridView1);

            MyCell Cell;
            for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    int n = i + AsciA;
                    string CellName = (char)n + (j + 1).ToString();
                    Cell = new MyCell();
                    Cell.Val = "0";
                    Cell.Exp = "";
                    dataSaver.Add(CellName, Cell);
                }

            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            MyCell Cell;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                int n = i + AsciA;
                string CellName = (char)n + (dataGridView1.RowCount).ToString();
                Cell = new MyCell();
                Cell.Val = "0";
                Cell.Exp = "";
                Cell.Name = CellName;
                MessageBox.Show(CellName);
                dataSaver.Add(CellName, Cell);
            }
            SetRowNum(dataGridView1);
            RefreshCell();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
            DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            column.CellTemplate = cell;
            string _name = SetColNum();
            column.Name = _name;
            column.HeaderText = _name;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

            MyCell Cell;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string CellName = _name + (i+1).ToString();
                Cell = new MyCell();
                Cell.Val = "0";
                Cell.Exp = "";
                Cell.Name = CellName;
                dataSaver.Add(CellName, Cell);
            }
            RefreshCell();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("NO ROWS TO DELETE");
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    string delCell;
                    delCell = dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText + (dataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(delCell);
                    dataSaver.Remove(delCell);
                }
                RefreshCell();
            }
        }
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void SetRowNum(DataGridView data)
        {
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                row.HeaderCell.Value = String.Format("{0}", row.Index + 1);

            }
        }
        private void RefreshCell()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {

                    string cellName = (char)(j + AsciA) + (i + 1).ToString();
                    string expression = dataSaver[cellName].Exp;
                    if (expression != "")
                    {
                        var result = 228; //ExelCalculator.Evaluate(expression, cellName);
                        dataSaver[cellName].Val = Convert.ToString(result);
                        dataGridView1[j, i].Value = dataSaver[cellName].Val;
                    }
                    else
                        dataGridView1[j, i].Value = "";
                }
            }
        }
        private string SetColNum()
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Columns.Count + AsciA;
            if (n <= 89)
            {
                return Char.ToString((char)n);
            }
            else
            {
                return "x";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если что, третья кнопка отвечает за удаления рядка, первые две за добавления рядка и столбика

Comment: подправь вопрос и кинь код только функции которая удаляет рядок. Остальные не обязаны выискивать из груды кода нужный метод, который, еще и назван в стиле ButtonN_Click

Comment: я думаю без остального кода не будет понятно

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в DataGrid твой лист как dataSource.

Тогда он будет автоматически обновлятся как только ты обновишь данные в самом листе. И не нужно будет вручную добавлять и удалять данные и из листа и из датагрида вручную.

Удалил ил листа - он автоматом обновился.

В таком случае ты избавишся от минимум 70% этого кода.

А еще называй функции по-человечески. По названию метода должно быть видно что он делает. 
Да и названия кнопок не оставляй автоматически сгенерированными.

Comment: только в таком случае, чтобы работал двусторонний биндинг лучше простой лист заменить на `BindingList`, иначе `DataGrid` не подхватит редактирование элементов.